# How can I get a range argument in a spreadsheet custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get the position of the range in the argument, like:

```
// Tells your range's row position
function myFunction(range){
  return range.getRow();
}
```

which is obviously already tested and doesn't work.

Any clues?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What I have below works for me and I am unable to recreate the problem.

    'function myFunction(range){
      return range.getRow();
    }
     
    function testMain(){
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1);
      Logger.log(myFunction(range));
    }'

Comment: If you only want to know which row a range starts in, you could use `ROW(reference)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any range parameters that you use when calling a custom function are evaluated first by the spreadsheet, and passed as either a single value or as an array of values. There is no spreadsheet value that maps into a Range object.

You could instead pass your range as a string, and then have your custom function use the string in a call to Sheet.getRange().

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662782/1677912) contains an example of this technique.

Comment: Thank you, Mogsdad.  There's no solution for me.  What I wanted to do is get the range' sheet.  And I needed a range because user will move the range and rename sheets, so the range in a formula would update automatically.